# Dynamic Type definition for a Char Field with variable length

Tags: dynamic, types, char, abap

For internal usage I need to define a structured type with one of the fields being a char-field with a variable length.

Something like this (I hope this example clarifies my problem):

```
DATA: lv_type TYPE char7.
lv_type = 'char128'. "The actual length will be determined during execution of the program

TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_satzcounter,
       satza TYPE zedist,
       addit TYPE (lv_type), "<----- Something like this (obviously, it doesn't work like 
                             "       this, but I think it clarifies my question)
       menge TYPE int1,
       END OF ty_satzcounter.

DATA: lt_satzcounter TYPE TABLE OF ty_satzcounter,
      ls_satzcounter TYPE ty_satzcounter.
...
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character variable with dynamic length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052797/character-variable-with-dynamic-length)

Comment: Asked by me 7 years ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of dynamic typing is not possible, but for your purpose, character type with dynamic length, there is the type [`string`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring.htm):

```
TYPES: satza TYPE zedist,
       addit TYPE string,
...
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your answer! Is there really no way to archieve this, using RTTS e.g.?

Comment: @Allocortex: it would be possible to define a dynamc internal table during runtime with RTTS, but for me in this case it does not make much sense. If my understanding is correct, it is just one text field,which can have any length during runtime. And for that purpose we have TYPE string in ABAP. So, why use a rather complicated solution, when there is a simple and straightforward one.

Comment: Again, thanks for your fast reply! I do totally understand your point there. I will try out do overthink my concept in this point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am absolutely with JozsefSzikszai's solution, but for demonstrating the additional complexity of dynamic structures and tables, here a possible solution as example:

```
"your input
DATA(lv_charlength) = 128.
"or
DATA(lv_type) = 'CHAR128'.

DATA:
      lro_structdescr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
      lro_tabledescr  TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr,
      lro_datadescr   TYPE REF TO cl_abap_datadescr,
      lro_typedescr   TYPE REF TO cl_abap_typedescr,
      lt_component    TYPE abap_component_tab,
      ls_component    TYPE LINE OF abap_component_tab,
      lro_wa          TYPE REF TO data.

    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_wa> TYPE any.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_tab> TYPE table.


* determine components of structure -> lt_component    
    ls_component-name = 'SATZA'.
    ls_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_name( 'ZEDIST' ).
    APPEND ls_component TO lt_component.

    ls_component-name = 'ADDIT'.
    ls_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>get_c( p_length = lv_charlength ).
    APPEND ls_component TO lt_component.

    "or
*   ls_component-name = 'ADDIT'.
*   ls_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_name( lv_type ).
*   APPEND ls_component TO lt_component.

    ls_component-name = 'MENGE'.
    ls_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_name( 'INT1' ).
    APPEND ls_component TO lt_component.

* get structure descriptor -> lro_STRUCTDESCR
    lro_structdescr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>create( lt_component ).

* create work area of structure lro_STRUCTDESCR -> lro_WA
    CREATE DATA lro_wa TYPE HANDLE lro_structdescr.
*    ASSIGN lro_wa->* TO <fs_wa>. "work area/structure to use

    lro_datadescr ?= lro_structdescr.
    lro_tabledescr ?= cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( lro_datadescr ).

* Create dynmaic internal table
    CREATE DATA et_range_tab TYPE HANDLE lro_tabledescr.
*    ASSIGN et_range_tab->* TO <fs_tab>. "table to use
```

Comment: Thank you too, for your fast and detailed answer!

I will overthink my concept in this point. Maybe using a String really is the better solution for my problem.

Thank you very much for your detailed explanation!